# Compute a boolean result of multiple value/operator from a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, boolean-logic

I have a table returning me a series of boolean(0/1) paired with an operator (and/or) as follow

e.g.

| ID | Operator | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | and | 0 |
| 2 | and | 0 |
| 3 | or | 1 |

I am trying to find an efficient way to parse these rows into a single result that would be equivalent to

```
(false and false or true) //returning true
```

I think this would be possible with CLR, but it appear to be something I could do in regular T-SQL. I've thought about scalar function receiving a table variable. Would this be my best course of action at this stage?

The table will never be very complex and always start with an AND operator which can be ignored.

As pointed out in comment, I was going to do this with a simple AND and if I have any OR it would shortcut the entire thing, but I am doubting my own self as when I tried this in JS it doesn't appear to be the case: https://jsfiddle.net/3ctshxae/

Edit: I incorrectly stated I would process them in as a stack since that is what made sense to me initially. I never thought about orders of operators without brackets as one would simply never write them that way when programming. I indeed would like to respect precedence rules of Boolean logic of ANDs taking precedence.

I know I could do this in a CLR and simply throw the logic in it and get the returned value, but I was hoping to avoid stepping outside of T-SQL.

Comment: You order by the ID?

Comment: Should all `AND`s be applied before `OR`s or they should be processed in a stack manner?

Comment: Could be any number of rows? And you never have brackets? Cos without brackets your ORs will always override everything else.

Comment: @astentx in a stack manner as they come

Comment: @DaleK Assuming we go for the standard "`and` precedes `or`" I can't see a way to do this without recursion, and I think that's never going to perform as well as a simple `while` loop. Can't believe I've just said that.

Comment: @DaleK I thought about this until I tried it in JS where that doesn't seem to be the case? https://jsfiddle.net/3ctshxae/

Comment: @DaleK no bracket, I have containers in there as well grouped by parentID, but I'm breaking them down to simpler components already using a while loop.

Comment: I wasn't being quite correct when I said "OR" shortcuts it, the actual rules are "When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, the AND operators are evaluated first." which means order is important.

Comment: @DaleK that make much more sense and explains the JS result I am seeing.

Comment: Added precision that I do intend to process them with precedence rules intact. Therefore AND grouped first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally one would process this using precedence rules: `and` comes before `or`, and this would complicate things immensely.

But if you want to process this in a very simple stack manner, where each item is processed in order, you can rearrange this in the following manner.

- Since `(A AND B) OR C` is the same as `C OR (A AND B)`, we can simply look for all `and`s separately from `or`
- We can ignore any `or` condition which is `false` because any other condition will override it
- We need all `and` conditions to be true

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN
        (COUNT(CASE WHEN Operator = 'and' AND value = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Operator = 'and' AND value = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0)
  OR COUNT(CASE WHEN Operator = 'or' AND value = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM YourTable;
```

---

You say that actually you *do* want to use precedence rules. You have no brackets, so that makes things easier.

So we can formulate it like this:

- Any `or` which is false can be ignored
- Any `or` which is true overrides anything else
- Group all `and`s together in islands, and evaluate each island separately
- Any island of all trues is true, all others are false

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN
  EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE Operator = 'or' AND value = 1)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Operator ORDER BY ID) grouping
        FROM YourTable t
    ) t
    WHERE Operator = 'and'
    GROUP BY grouping
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
  )
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: I was incorrect in my question and the comment made me realize I do indeed intend to process them with the precedence rules intact. Edited the question.

Comment: @jfrobishow OK I've given you a solution for that also

Comment: that works very well, thank you! I have never seen a grouping done with a calculation like you're doing. I think it's pairing the "islands" is that it?

Comment: Yes it's a technique known as "gaps and islands"